# How to connect to Postgresql database - Openproject

Tags: postgresql, openproject

I have installed the community edition of the Openproject in the ubuntu desktop.
Openproject automatically installed PostgreSql in the ubuntu system.
I have installed the pgadmin software in my ubuntu system to connect to postgresql.
I want to know how to connect to the database and generate the report 
Thanks in advance for your valuable answers

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu environment you can open terminal and switch into postgres user and create new DB user with superuser permissions:

```
sudo su - postgres
createuser --interactive --pwprompt
```

After user created you can use it credentials to connect to DB using any cli/gui tool.

I recommend [DBeaver Community Edition](https://dbeaver.io/download/) as PostgreSQL GUI tool.